# Want to scrape a list containing different companies using Selenium framework

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape this list automatically one by one but using for loop gives me errors.
This is my code.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\webdriver\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
sleep(3)
search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

subjectlist=["Acsys Inc",
"Customs Service Of Republic Of Armenia",
"National Security Service Under Government Of Ra",
"Aeropuerto Internacional Reina Beatrix",
"Algeme Ziektekosten Verzekering",
"Algemene",
"Algemene Ziektenkosten Verzekering",
"Centrale Bank Aruba",
"Didata Ny Warehouse"
]


for i in subjectlist:
    search_query.send_keys(subjectlist[0])
    list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('cite')
```

Comment: where is `i`...`search_query.send_keys(subjectlist[i])`

Comment: This for loop is wrong

Comment: Actually i am newbie to this so please can you help me with it @Wen

Comment: Not sure what you need to do

Comment: I want to scrape the scriptlist items one by one

Comment: Inside the for loop, you should reference i instead of subjectlist[0]

Comment: @Wen Shouldn't it be `search_query.send_keys(i)`?

Comment: I have but it then takes the whole list instead of first element then scoond

Comment: I want to control i such that it first ectracts first object then second and furthermore

Comment: i have used this but it kinda takes first element of list 
for i in subjectlist:
 search_query.send_keys(i)